# How to set the default value of a field in the database model class to the return value of a function？

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I use Flask-SQLAlchemy. the model class in picture.

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(60))
    slug = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

The default value of the slug field wants to be set as the return value of a function slugify(), and the title of the slugify() function needs to be passed in. How to set up in this case. Is it necessary to rewrite the save method?

Answer (score 0):

rewrite the **init**() function. It works.